# Short a 2D MxM matrix to a 2D (M-1)x(M-1) matrix from an arbitrari point A[i,j]

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra

I'm migrating my MATLAB code to phyton with numpy and scipy.

And I'm looking for a simple order to short a MxM matrix (or 2D array)

Example, I whish to remove all "0" from matrix at column 3 and row 3

```
[[a a 0 a]
 [a a 0 a]
 [0 0 0 0]
 [a a 0 a]]
```

And take this matrix

```
[[a a a]
[a a a]
[a a a]]
```

With only one line of code in numpy or scipy, if possible.

Comment: What one liner are you using in MATLAB?

Comment: Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927180/how-do-i-remove-all-zero-elements-from-a-numpy-array) maybe it's useful, @JPS.

Comment: The code I used is simple in MATLAB, to delete the 3rd row is:
A(3,:)=[]
Then to delete the 3rd column
A(:,3)=[]

Comment: Thanks Sidou, but I don't want to remove the values equals to 0, I wish to cut specific rows and columns of a 2D matrix

Comment: That's two lines!  That style of indexed delete works on lists, but not arrays.  There is a `np.delete` function that could be applied in the same way.  It could even be chained to fit on one line.   It doesn't operate in-place.

Comment: Alternatively `np.block` could be used to build a new array from 4 2d slices.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from this post:

[How to delete columns in numpy.array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642730/how-to-delete-columns-in-numpy-array)

The instruction is numpy.delete, for a A nxn array to delete any "i" row (axis=0)

```
A=np.delete(A,i,0)
```

To delete any "j" column (axis=1)

```
A=np.delete(A,j,1)
```

I tried and works in Spyder.